# R equal sampling takes too long

Tags: r, optimization, time, sample, random

I want to sample rows from different years given some constraints.

Say my dataset looks like this:

```
library(data.table)
dataset = data.table(ID=sample(1:21), Vintage=c(1989:1998, 1989:1998, 1992), Region.Focus=c("Europe", "US", "Asia"))
> dataset
    ID Vintage Region.Focus
 1:  7    1989       Europe
 2: 10    1990           US
 3: 20    1991         Asia
 4: 18    1992       Europe
 5:  4    1993           US
 6: 17    1994         Asia
 7: 13    1995       Europe
 8:  9    1996           US
 9: 12    1997         Asia
10:  3    1998       Europe
11: 11    1989           US
12: 14    1990         Asia
13:  8    1991       Europe
14: 16    1992           US
15: 19    1993         Asia
16:  1    1994       Europe
17:  5    1995           US
18: 15    1996         Asia
19:  6    1997       Europe
20: 21    1998           US
21:  2    1992         Asia
    ID Vintage Region.Focus
```

I want to 1,000 draws of sample size 2 and 4 (separate from each other) spread along two years. E.g. for 1,000 draws of sample size 2, it could be the first and the second row. I also have a constraint that the sample must consist of rows with the same region focus. My solution is the code below, but it is way too slow.

```
for(i in c(2,4)) {
  simulate <- function(i) {
    repeat{
      start <- dataset[sample(nrow(dataset), 1, replace=TRUE),]
      t <- start$Vintage:(start$Vintage + 1)
      matches <- which(dataset$Vintage %in% t & dataset$Region.Focus == start$Region.Focus) #constraints
      DT <- dataset[matches,]
      DT <- as.data.table(DT)
      x <- DT[,.SD[sample(.N,min(.N,i/length(t)))],by = Vintage]
      if(nrow(x) ==i) {
        x <- as.data.frame(x)
        x <- x %>% mutate(EqualWeight = 1 / i) %>% mutate(RandomWeight = prop.table(runif(i)))
        x <- ungroup(x)
        return(x)
      } else {
        x <- 0
      }
    }

  }
  #now replicate the expression 1000 times
  r <- replicate(1000, simulate(i), simplify=FALSE)
  r <- rbindlist(r, idcol="draw")
  f <- as.data.frame(r)
  write.csv(p, file=paste("Performance.fof.5", i, "csv", sep="."))
  fof <- paste("fof.5", i, sep = ".")
  assign(fof, f)
}
```

This code is very slow. My initial intuition is that my approach would need a lot of funds and keeps looping due to the constraint. I have 5,800 rows.

Is there a way other than the repeat function that results in a lot of looping? Perhaps there is another way of expressing the line `DT[,.SD[sample(.N,min(.N,i/length(t)))],by = Vintage]` to get rid off the repeat expression? Thank you in advance for any input!

Comment: Are you looking to sample the dataset, with one result having 2 rows and the other of 4 rows a 1000 times?

Comment: This is probably a second order speed boost, but you might consider, filling the sets of rows corresponding to each vintage-region combo in a list prior to your loops.  This would avoid the repeated `which` call and the operation would be near O(1). Something like `myRegionTime <- paste(region, time:(time+1), sep="."); matches <-  c(myList[[myRegionTime[1]]], myList[[myRegionTime[2]]])`.

Comment: Apparently, you forgot to include Value.USD. Maybe simplify your example...

Comment: @Arun, as a result I am looking for two data frames of 1,000 portfolios each. The data frames would have 2,000 and 4,000 rows, respectively. This has already worked well for a random distribution amongst the chosen years.

Comment: @lmo: that's a good approach. However, the actual dataset I have has vintage years from 1977-2011 and 4 regions, so there would be a lot of combinations, if I understood you correctly.

Comment: I think this would just be a list that has 136 elements, each of which contains the row numbers for the respective region-year. This is not too large and would save on a bunch of "==" look ups.